# Bus.bus Unavailable after workers greater then 0

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

This is my odoo-server.conf

```
admin_passwd = <pwd>
xmlrpc_port = 8069
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path=<path>
dbfilter = <dbname>
limit_memory_soft = 2629145600
limit_memory_hard = 4677721600
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 1200
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 8
```

I have already follow the step for enabled workers.(Except SSL)

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache to reverse proxy?

Comment: In multi process mode you must run odoo with web server

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure the apache or nginx to reverse proxy to handle the longpolling request.